# Accessing function of remote pc

Tags: java, networking

There are 2 computers connected via internet. The first pc has `first.class` file and remote pc has `second.class` file.

I want to access one of the function of the remote pc (that has `second.class` file). How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) (remote method invocation). Read the tutorial and you'll see how you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [RMI (Remote Method Invocation)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html)

Answer (score 1):

With a Remote Procedure Call ([RPC](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)) such as [RMI](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) or [RPC-XML](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Java_API_for_XML-based_RPC).

Answer (score 0):

You need [Java RMI](http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~cs379/DistributedSystems/rmi_tut.html) for that kind of distributed systems, check that attached link.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst RMI can help, you should take a look at [Akka's Remote Actors](http://doc.akka.io/remote-actors-java) for a higher level (easier-to-use) abstraction.

Comment: Judging from the seeming know-how level of the question, I'd say it's too early to start with third-party APIs.

Comment: True enough, but at least for RMI there's tons of know-how/tutorials around. An area where *any* third-party library can only lag behind.